# How would get an email server reputation via cli or script?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, email-bounces, dig

I am trying to monitor email server reputation via cli or script
i.e. https://www.senderbase.org/

I found a way supposedly to do it via dig, but the output appears to be very incorrect. It indicates I am PRUDENTIAL in US and that server is in Japan. 
So I am looking for an option #2

## dig txt 107.191.60.48.query.senderbase.org

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.2 <<>> txt 107.191.60.48.query.senderbase.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11950
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;107.191.60.48.query.senderbase.org. IN TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
107.191.60.48.query.senderbase.org. 20220 IN TXT "0-0=1|1=THE PRUDENTIAL INSURANCE COMPANY OF AMERICA|2=5.9|3=5.7|4=40839|6=0|7=1|8=16843264|9=20040|45=N|46=8|48=24|50=Newark|51=NJ|52=07102|53=US|54=-74.1724|55=40.7357"

;; Query time: 139 msec
;; SERVER: 108.61.10.10#53(108.61.10.10)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 04 05:49:25 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 244
```

## traceroute 107.191.60.48

```
traceroute to 107.191.60.48 (107.191.60.48), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.247.2.2 (10.247.2.2)  0.810 ms  0.475 ms  0.539 ms
 2  xe-7-3-1.edge5.London1.Level3.net (212.187.138.145)  21.512 ms  0.302 ms  0.224 ms
 3  ae-3.r00.londen10.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.9.125)  0.941 ms  0.873 ms  0.933 ms
 4  ae-7.r23.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.6.54)  8.467 ms  8.362 ms  0.678 ms
 5  ae-3.r22.amstnl02.nl.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.5.198)  8.534 ms  7.446 ms  11.019 ms
 6  ae-3.r25.tokyjp05.jp.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.4.64)  236.855 ms  252.462 ms  246.120 ms
 7  ae-2.r01.tokyjp03.jp.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.6.170)  246.744 ms  260.765 ms  265.163 ms
 8  xe-0-0-0-30.r01.tokyjp03.jp.ce.gin.ntt.net (203.105.72.214)  259.863 ms  268.099 ms  262.274 ms
 9  72.ae2.sw1.tko1.jp.scnet.net (50.31.249.198)  260.921 ms  260.465 ms  255.284 ms
10  br1.tyo1.gameservers.com (50.31.249.202)  279.643 ms  264.215 ms  249.935 ms
11  r2d2 (107.191.60.48)  259.012 ms  259.015 ms  252.303 ms
```

How would a monitor an email server reputation via script or cli?

Comment: You have to reverse your ip when querying senderbase: `dig txt 48.60.191.107.query.senderbase.org`.

Comment: @baf you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test an ip in `senderbase.org` database you have to query their dns server for a `txt` record with a specially constructed domain name. It should be a sequence of bytes **in reverse order** representing an IPv4 address, encoded as decimal numbers, separated by dots with the suffix `.query.senderbase.org`.

In your particular case:

```
dig txt 48.60.191.107.query.senderbase.org
```